# Setting up email settings in appsettings web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Setting up email details in web.config - but no email is being sent!

```xml
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="smtpServer" value="smtp.live.com" />
    <add key="EnableSsl" value = "true"/>
    <add key="smtpPort" value="587" />
    <add key="smtpUser" value="MyEmail@live.co.uk" />
    <add key="smtpPass" value="mypasswordgoeshere" />
    <add key="adminEmail" value="no-reply@no-reply.com" />
  </appSettings>
```

I am using the following class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;

namespace MVCcars.Utils
{
  public static class MailClient
  {
    private static readonly SmtpClient Client;
    static MailClient()
    {
      Client = new SmtpClient
      {
        Host =
          ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServer"],
        Port =
          Convert.ToInt32(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpPort"]),
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network

      };
      Client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
      Client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpUser"],
      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpPass"]);
    }


    private static bool SendMessage(string from, string to,
      string subject, string body)
    {
      MailMessage mm = null;
      bool isSent = false;
      try
      {
        // Create our message
        mm = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
        mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions =
        DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
        // Send it
        Client.Send(mm);
        isSent = true;
      }
      // Catch any errors, these should be logged and
      // dealt with later
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        // If you wish to log email errors,
        // add it here...
        var exMsg = ex.Message;
      }
      finally
      {
        mm.Dispose();
      }
      return isSent;
    }


    public static bool SendWelcome(string email)
    {
      string body = "Put welcome email content here...";
      return SendMessage(
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["adminEmail"],
          email, "Welcome message", body);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the Account controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Attempt to register the user
        MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
        Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName,
          model.Password, model.Email, null, null,
          true, null, out createStatus);
        if (createStatus ==
            MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
        {
          // Send welcome email
          MailClient.SendWelcome(model.Email);
          FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(
            model.UserName,
            false /* createPersistentCookie */);
          return RedirectToAction("create", "Customer");
        }
        else
        {
          ModelState.AddModelError("",
            ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
        }
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed,
    // redisplay form
    return View(model);   
}
```

Are the app settings in the web.config right for the enableSsl?
any advice welcome

Comment: Do you have something that will READ these appSettings and set them on your SMTP object?

Comment: With the code you've added, are you getting an exception? What is happening? I don't see where you've set it to enableSSL in your code, maybe I overlooked it. You would need Client.EnableSsl = bool.parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSsl"]) in your code

Comment: The code: Client.EnableSsl = bool.parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSsl"]) whrere would you put it in the class

Comment: In the block of code Client = new SmtpClient { .. } where you're creating an instance of the SmtpClient. Where you have { Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServer"], ....} add { Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServer"], EnableSsl = bool.parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSsl"]), ...}

Comment: getting error on parse (bool does not conatin a definition for parse)

Comment: Sorry, its a Capital P, Parse, not parse. If that fails, use Convert.ToBoolean

Comment: As a suggestion, if you have time to, I would refactor your code to make use of the system.network settings in your config file. Using the code you have you've forced yourself to have a username/password for any time you want to send mail. There may be a time where that isn't needed and you would need to recompile the app. Keeping the settings in a single location (that is already managed internally for SmtpClient) is advised. You can easily change the config file to meet your setting needs without changing your code to remove credentials or something else down the line.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An even easier way to work with the SmtpClient in .NET is to use the system.net configuration settings. This will allow you to set the defaults for any SmtpClient that is created without having to write code to set all of the properties. This way you can easily modify the entire setup without changing any code.

```xml
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="no-reply@no-reply.com">
        <network host="smtp.live.com" password="mypasswordgoeshere" port="587" userName="MyEmail@live.co.uk"  enableSsl="true"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

And then in code

```
 System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
 smtp.Send(mailMessage);
```

**EDIT** Here's the orginal code I posted below:

```
static MailClient() 
{ 
     Client = new SmtpClient 
     { 
         Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServer"], 
         Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpPort"]), 
         DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
         EnableSsl = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSsl"])

     };
  .....
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Nick Bork's answer above you may need to make some changes to your asp page and use the

> MailSettingsGroup

. Hope this link is helpful
[How to use the Not-so-new MailSettingsSectionGroup](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/01/27/how-to-use-the-notsonew-mailsettingssectiongroup)

Comment: You shouldn't NEED to use that config code namespace because the default constructor of the SmtpClient should handle that for you.... but it would come in handy if you ever needed to READ the settings in your application for any reason (including sending of email if need be)